# Getting the name of a child class in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Lets say I'm building a base class which will be extended upon by the children class. So a base class is called `Base` and children can be `Child1`, `Child2`, etc.

In the base class's constructor, how can i get the value of Child1/Child2?

This is all using PHP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A base class should really never depend on information about child classes---

To answer your question:

```
class base {
    public function __construct() {
        print "Class:" . get_class($this) . "\n";
    }
}

class child extends base{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
$c = new child();
```

Just for future reference -- this can be acheived in a static context using get_called_class(), but this is only available in PHP >= 5.3

Comment: I know that this is a bit old, but thought I'd mention that it works for me in php 5.2.17

Comment: "A base class should really never depend on information about child classes" -- what about abstract classes. It might me useful in some cases where you have to route stuff around.

Answer (score 10):

simply call [get_class](http://php.net/get_class)($this) - note however that a base class method has no real business in changing its behaviour depending on which derived class is using it. That's the whole point of deriving a class :)

Comment: If you try to implement a very simple MVC framework, having the NAME of the child class to find a view is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Didn't know about `get_class`, disregard this one ;)

You could try `__CLASS__` but it might not work properly.

A work-around could be to specify the class name as a property of the base class.

**Edit:** This does not work (I used the following code)
    construct() {
            echo __CLASS;
        }
    }

```
class b extends a {}

$b = new b;
```

I would suggest passing the name of $b as a parameter to A, for example:

```
<?php
class a {
    protected $name;
    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

class b extends a {
    protected $name = __CLASS__;
}

$b = new b;
```