# Get all defined classes of a parent class in php

Tags: php, oop, class

I need to determine, after all files have been included, which classes extend a parent class, so:

```
class foo{
}
class boo extends foo{
}
class bar extends foo{
}
```

and I'd like to be able to grab an array like:

```
array('boo','bar');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538863/getting-the-name-of-a-child-class-in-php

Comment: not quite, that requires the constructor function to be run, I'm looking for declared classes that have not necessarily been run yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all extended Classes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680040/get-all-extended-classes-in-php)

Comment: Except those was asked 2 years before that....

Comment: it depends on what do you want to do after getting all the classes that implement and interface/extend a class

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you need that, it really smells like bad code, the base class shouldn't need to know this.

However, if you definitions have been included (i.e. you don't need to include new files with classes you possibly have), you could run:

```
$children  = array();
foreach(get_declared_classes() as $class){
    if($class instanceof foo) $children[] = $class;
}
```

Comment: this is basically what I have, except I'm using `is_a` instead of `instanceof`... and I understand why you would think that, but the base class doesn't actually need to know anything, this is more like a plugin manager function:)

Comment: Ack, that could be a valid case. If that's basically what you have, does it not work / is there an issue, or are you just asking to confirm there isn't a better/faster method?

Comment: Check, if it's in a plugin-manager with volatile plugins, you might want to perform a syntax check on files before including them to prevent fatal parse errors, but that's about it I guess.

Comment: It's a bit old, but you could use `is_subclass_of` [(link)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php) instead of `is_a` and `instanceof`.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBonAmi; your answer worked but `is_a()` and `instanceof` did not for me because both expect an object, not a classname.

Comment: Normally this should fail, because modern applications will use autoloading and in this case classes are not defined. get_declared_classes() will return a list of an undefined application state, because some classes are loaded and others not.

Comment: @MatthiasKleine: indeed, hence the _"However, if you definitions have been included (i.e. you don't need to include new files with classes you possibly have)"_ there. If this isn't the case, it's impossible to do in a sane way. But as stated, the requested functionality itself is a bit iffy already :)

Comment: I'd like to add that, this does not smell like "Bad Code" -- it's more in the lines with Dynamic Class Reflection, which is why reflection functions exist and why there is a lot of benefit to dynamic class creation / loading.

Comment: @phillihp: I disagree. If you are talking about knowing parent classes, implemented interfaces, or even traits, I'm with you. Knowing all possible classes (that are potentially not loaded or known yet) that extend a class is not. This in no way blocks you from creating dynamic classes in any way, nor is it a requirement for it. Still, if a (dynamic or not) class wants to be used by a certain instance or class, the proper way to do that is signaling, not auto-discovery, as this would limit your options to blacklist or filter this list (undefining a class is to my knowledge not possible in PHP).

Comment: how could `($class instanceof foo)`  work of `$class` is a string and not a class. Don't you need somehow to create an instance of it?

Comment: THIS ANSWER DOESN'T WORK! `instanceof` expects an instance, not a string. Use `is_subclass_of()` (as suggested below) which does.

Answer (score 31):

Taking Wrikken's answer and correcting it using Scott BonAmi's suggestion and you get:

```
$children = array();
foreach( get_declared_classes() as $class ){
  if( is_subclass_of( $class, 'foo' ) )
    $children[] = $class;
}
```

The other suggestions of `is_a()` and `instanceof` don't work for this because both of them expect an instance of an object, not a classname.

Answer (score 7):

Use

`$allClasses = get_declared_classes();`

to get a list of all classes.

Then, use [PHP's Reflection feature](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to build the inheritance tree.

Comment: I know this is old now, but thank you for pointing me to the reflection classes, they lack the complete documentation of most of php.net, but they are extremely useful in a few different places +1

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that the following solution or some thing like that would be a good fit for your problem. IMHO, you can do the following (which is kind of observer pattern):

1- Define an interface call it `Fooable`

```
interface Fooable{
    public function doSomething();
}
```

2- All your **target** classes must implement that interface:

```
class Fooer implements Fooable{
    public function doSomething(){
         return "doing something";
    }
}

class SpecialFooer implements Fooable{
    public function doSomething(){
         return "doing something special";
    }
}
```

3- Make a **registrar class** call it the `FooRegisterar`

```
class FooRegisterar{
    public static $listOfFooers =array();

    public static function register($name, Fooable $fooer){
         self::$listOfFooers[$name]=$fooer;
    }
    public static function getRegisterdFooers(){
         return self::$listOfFooers;
    }
}
```

4- Somewhere in your boot script or some script that is included in the boot script:

```
FooRegisterar::register("Fooer",new Fooer());
FooRegisterar::register("Special Fooer",new SpecialFooer());
```

5- In your main code:

```
class FooClient{

    public function fooSomething(){
         $fooers = FooRegisterar::getRegisterdFooers();
         foreach($fooers as $fooer){
              $fooer->doSomthing();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the comments and the accepted answer, the problem is that I 1.) didn't want to have to know about the child classes ahead of time (your step 4 requires me to register each child class) and 2.) I didn't want to actually instantiate the classes, just have a list of them.

Comment: let me ask you the question in a different way, why would you need this? I mean why would you need to get all the classes that do inherit a class without knowing them ahead of the time?

Comment: You marked your question as OOP that's why I am posting this answer because this is how an OOP solution looks like :)

Comment: not to mention that the accepted answer may imply a "performance issue"

Comment: Doesn't really matter why, when I asked this 5 years ago I was building a plugin auto loader, knowing that I could potentially have a few hundred plugins, but only a dozen on some page loads, the accepted answer allows me to cache the results and doesn't require that I know about all of the classes or instantiate them.

Comment: I understand plugins as things that can be loaded in a system by registering them into the system using some sort of registration method (that will allow you to identify what and how many plugins do you have). What I mean is, if you want to apply an object oriented solution it has to be fully OOP right?

Comment: Not sure how many different ways I can say this. The plugin system itself is OOP, I was looking for a dynamic way to find and register these plugins without instantiating them, your "solution" would be a possible way to implement the registration of plugins on page load, but doesn't address the dynamic need of discovering the plugins. Where do you get "Fooer" and "Special Fooer" from if you don't already know they exist?

Comment: no need to be nervous and to talk that way I am sorry to answer your question ... never mind :)

Comment: no one is nervous, you didn't answer my question, you provided a solution that would be perfectly acceptable if the requirements were different.