# Return an array of children to a PHP class?

Tags: php, object

Let's say I have a class like:

```
class father {
    function __construct() {
        $msg = "Blah...\n";
        print $msg;
    }

    function doSomething() {
        $msg = get_class($this) . " does something...\n";
        print $msg;
    }
}
```

And a child class like:

```
class child extends father {
    function __construct() {
        $this->doSomething()
    }
}
```

And:

```
class eldest extends father {
    function __construct() {
        $this->doSomething()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to return an array of *the present instances* of the children of the father class (child and eldest in this case)?

Comment: do you mean if there is a way to find out which child class is in use?

Comment: I believe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671398/get-all-defined-classes-of-a-parent-class-in-php

Comment: No, return an array of instances of all of the children of the father class. Is that possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible, and you shouldnt need to.

Comment: @John tecnically you could iterate over `get_defined_vars()` and check if they are subclasses of given class - though I don't know how useful it would be.

Comment: @moonwave Yes, you are right. Nice method :-)

Comment: It's useful because I'm creating an IRC bot and this is a way to efficiently load plugin. Each plugin class will have a "hooks" function that will return the names of all the hooks that can be used to call the command. When one of the hooks match the the hook called the bot will initiate an instance of the class which the hook would call.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to get every class that extends `father`, you should have a trip around all declared classes via [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php):

```
$subclasses = array();

foreach(get_declared_classes() as $class)
{

    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);  
    $reflection -> isSubClassOf('father') && $subclasses[] = $class;

}

var_dump($subclasses);
```

And check the results.

EDIT: if you need to know about *instances*, iterate over `get_defined_vars()` - but why do you need to know this?