# How to get the name of the classes which extends a specific class in php

Tags: php

let I have a class named A.
I have another two classes B and C.
Both are extended from the class A.
Now I want to get the name of the classes which is extended from class A i.e. B and C.

```
class A{
}
class B extends A{
}
class C extends A{
}
```

Now I want to get the name B and C.

I have tried using **instanceof**

```
$obj=new B();
if($obj instanceof A)
   echo "derived";
```

but to do so I have to know the class name.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php

Comment: And here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671398/get-all-defined-classes-of-a-parent-class-in-php

Comment: It's just giving the opposite means it's giving the parent names but I want to know the name of the child class which are extended from that classes.

Comment: In this case check answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6671567/4471134 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118179/4471134

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class A
{

}
class B extends A
{

}
class C extends A
{

}

$b = new B();

if ($b instanceof A) {
    var_dump(get_class($b)); // print B
    var_dump(get_parent_class($b)); // print A
}
```