# Fetch all existing models in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, model, laravel-4

Is there a way to fetch all existing models in Laravel 4? The documentation says nothing about this and googling the issue didn't result in anything relevant.

I'm working on a feature in my current project that needs the ability to create a report of which assets there are or which customer has bought which asset at the company. For that, I'm creating a module that allows the user to specify what information goes on which worksheet (exports to Excel).

Let's say I have the following models (They all extend Eloquent):

- Asset
- Customer
- Country
- Keys
- User

I only want the Asset and Customer model to be usable in the report. My idea is to give those a constant and check on that constant.

The only thing I'm bumping my head against is a way to fetch all the models that are defined in my Laravel application.

I know I could loop through the app/models directory or create an array somewhere but I'm looking for a better way of doing this. Does anyone happen to know how to achieve this?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6671567/2629998) which shows a way to get all classes that extend a parent class (in your case it's `Eloquent`).

Comment: I would create a repository or service provider class to handle the functionality you describe.  Then simply fetch the classes using Laravel's built-in IoC class.

Comment: @André `get_declared_classes()` does not list any model that is not called before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, and asking around in the PHP Chatroom I came with the following solution:

First I retrieve all models from the /app/models directory, removing *.* and *..* and trimming the extension off the file names and any leftover whitespace.
In my case this will work because I named the file after the classes.

```
private function getModels()
{
    return array_filter(scandir(app_path('models/')), function(&$val)
    {
        if($val != '.' && $val != '..')
        {
            $val = trim(str_replace('.php', '', $val));
            return class_exists($val);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I have all models I want, I need to filter which ones I want to have reported. On the models which I want to have reported, I implemented an interface called `IReportable`. I wanted to use an abstract class, but since PHP doesn't allow multiple inheritance I went with this method.

`class MyModel extends Eloquent implements IReportable`

Or in my case:

`Class Asset extends BaseModel implements IReportable`

With this, I can filter the models.

```
private function getReportableModels()
{
    return array_filter($this->getModels(), function($model)
    {
        return in_array('IReportable', class_implements($model, false));
    });
}
```