# TYPO3 : How to determine child-objecttypes of specific parent domain-model?

Tags: class, typo3, children, domain-model

I have some different domain-models, each being parent of different sub-models.
All of those domain-models extend themselves out of a basic model class and I want to write a general function in the base-model, that deals with subclasses of the current model. Therefore, I need to find a way, to dynamically get all child-model-classes of a given domain-model.
Can this be done somehow ? Perhaps via Object-Storage-Definitions or similar ?!

Update : as mentioned in the comment section, mny question had nothing to do with TYPO3, it was a general php-question .. solution for my question are reflection-classes.

Comment: Since my question was not described well I will try to make it more clear :
Is it possible, to check all properties of an initialized typo3-domain-model-object if they are of type object-storage and if so, return specific info about that related child model type (tablename, classname and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your question has nothing to do with TYPO3, so take a look at this general PHP question thread and possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671398/get-all-defined-classes-of-a-parent-class-in-php).

Comment: Indeed your link made me read about reflection-classes, which is exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about Database Relationships. Yes, this can be done in TYPO3.

Each `model` should be mapped to a `table`. So, let's take for example the `Category` domain model and `parent` property

```
class Category extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category
     */
    protected $parent = null;

    /**
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category 
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
      if ($this->parent instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyLoadingProxy) {
          $this->parent->_loadRealInstance();
      }
      return $this->parent;
  }

  /**
   * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category $parent
   */
  public function setParent(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category $parent)
  {
      $this->parent = $parent;
  }
```

The parent property will return the parent category. The same logic is when you want to get the childs.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My question (sorry if it was not described well) was, if it is possible, to check all properties of an initialized typo3-domain-model-object if they are of type object-storage and if so, return specific info about that related child model type (tablename, classname and so on) !?