# How to get all children of class php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, reflection

In my app there is a model called Role which extends Model, all existing roles extend that class. All of these roles have to be found via one method or function. However there's no documentation for Reflection in laravel, although it's unwanted to create another implementation of reflection in php. Laravel'ish solution is preferred, because replicating existing solution is meaningless

Comment: you dont have all the roles in an array or container object? its impossible to answer the question without seeing the full class structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all defined classes of a parent class in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671398/get-all-defined-classes-of-a-parent-class-in-php)

Comment: No, role is represented as eloquent model due to huge structure diffrence. For instance: teacher and student

Comment: @Artshellorok what do you actually look for is called relationships https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: In my app i have User model which has relations with roles: other models which extend Role (blueprint model), all such models(which extend Role) have to be found(doesn't matter which way, btw i tried getting all relationships as array(it's impossible)).

Comment: @Artshellorok Does the child classes like `Student` class have its own separate table or its still reflecting roles table?

Comment: Separate of course