# How to get the child name of class in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I want to get the child class name, in parent class constructor. The classes are namespaced so if I use get_class(); function, it will retrieve the entire namespace and I need only the class name of a child.

The parent class is a abstract class if that's matter.

Comment: what exactly are you doing? there may be a better way...

Comment: I'm using a framework which supports events. I have an abstract class which inserts some kind of data into database. I want to make a convention which will automate "fire()" some events, for example: Event::fire('{{child_class_name}}_insert', $something);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538863/getting-the-name-of-a-child-class-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283004/getting-the-name-of-a-child-class-in-the-parent-class-static-context

Comment: I'm using namespaces. I've already seen this topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fully qualified classname with namespace, is really the 'correct' class.
If you only want the last bit, you should simply substring.

```
$class = substr(get_class($this), strrpos(get_class($this),'\\')+1);
```

Alternatively you can use reflection

```
$refl = new \ReflectionObject($this);
$class = $refl->getShortName();
```

Comment: My class isn't on "last bit", so I can't substract it from the string. The class name doesn't have an "exact place" in the namespace string, so this is not a solution. Isn't there another way to do that?

Comment: The 'class part' is always the last part of the namespace string, no exceptions. If you mean to achieve something different, you should give an exact example.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `get_called_class()` function from [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)